# issue with if/elseif in_array inside foreach loop display only one post

Tags: functions, categories, loop, array, conditional-tags

I try to attribute a specific background-color to each post if one of categories of post corresponding to one category.
My function works but is restricted to display only one post in result.
If I delete this function, all post are displayed.

More informations :

On my page I have buttons to filter posts by category. if I click on once I display all post for this category. But each post contains several categories. I have selected some categories to attribute a background colors for each posts, but theses categories are different of the filters buttons.

Wordpress display this error "a critical error has occurred on your site, Learn more about debugging WordPress." after the first post displayed.

here is my entire code :

```
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_filter','filter_ajax');

function filter_ajax(){

$category = $_POST['category'];

$argsf = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

if(isset($category)){
    $argsf['category__in'] = array($category);
}

$postsf = get_posts($argsf);    

if (!empty($postsf)) {
    foreach ($postsf as $post) {
        
        $link_post = get_permalink( $post->ID );
        $image_post = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, $size = 'large' );
        $item1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'item1', true);
        $item2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'item2', true);
        $item3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'item3', true);
        $item4 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'item4', true);
        $title = get_the_title($post->ID); 
        $post_slug = $post->post_name;
        $cats_post = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
        
        function test($cats_post){
            if (in_array("14", $cats_post)){ echo'#710000';}
            elseif(in_array("5", $cats_post)){ echo'#0a005d';}
            elseif(in_array("16", $cats_post)){ echo'#65a0e8';}
            elseif(in_array("13", $cats_post)){ echo'#90744b';}
        }
    
?>  
<div class="shop w-24 pb-1" style="height:320px; min-width:320px;">
    <div class="w-100 h-100 p-2">
            
        <div class=" " style="background-color:<?php test($cats_post); ?>">
            <div class="">
                <!--<div class="" title="Locer">
                <a href="<?= $item2; ?>"><i class="icofont-opposite "></i></a>
                </div>-->
                <div class="" title="something">
                    <a href="tel:<?= $item3; ?>"><i class="im im-phone"></i> </a>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <span><?= $item1; ?></span>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <span class="text-uppercase col-white tsh332 fwlr text-center" style="font-size:2rem;">
                <?= $title; ?>
            </span>
            <?php if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post->ID , 'item4' ) ){ ?> 
                <div class="">
                    <div class="b-yellow b-100">
                        <span><?= $item4; ?> </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
                
    </div>
</div>
<?php  }  /* fin foreach */
    }  /* fin if  */
wp_reset_postdata();
die();
}

?>
```

I tried that but it doesn't work :

- get_the_category instead of wp_get_post_categories
- has_item instead of in_array

I don't know If I must use an other foreach loop and how !

thanks

Comment: What is the error?  Turn on debug and then post the error here. https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: I would avoid declaring functions inside other functions, it has no benefits and can make debugging difficult. It's easily fixed by moving the function out of the functiion and keeping the same name

Comment: I'm already on debug mode, I have only this error "a critical error has occurred on your site, Learn more about debugging WordPress." https://bit.ly/3fFRC3r

Comment: Also, why not do this via CSS? If you use the `post_class` API it will output HTML classes for every tag and category that you can then pick up using CSS to set the colour. There's no need to manually insert inline CSS styling on the fly

Comment: Tom, I tried to use the function outside foreach but I can't get wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID ). If it's possible how can I do that?

Comment: I read post_class use but I don't see how to match the post_class with specific category of this post !

Comment: Here the page :  bit.ly/3fFRC3r. By clicking on one of the categories I have the critical error of wordpress only after the first post. At least three categories filter have more than one post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several fatal assumptions here, and, a far better way to do it.

#### 1. Declaring Functions inside Functions

This will cause a fatal error in a future version of PHP,  makes it super difficult to debug. But worst, it's completely unnecessary.

This:

```php
function foo () { 
    function bar () {
        //
    }
    bar();
}
```

Should just be this:

```php
function bar() {
    //
}
function foo() {
    bar();
}
```

#### 2. Comparing strings and numbers, with a fuzzy `in_array`

`1` is not `"1"`, but because the 3rd parameter was never set to true, `1` is `"1"`. It's also `true`, and lots of other "truthy" values.

#### 3. Relying on hardcoded magic values

Don't hardcode the category ID. If you delete it by accident and recreate it, the ID will change. If you migrate to a new site the ID will change. It's very easy to break.

If you can't let the user pick a term, at least use a known slug/name so it can be recreated/set.

#### 4. Assuming the functions would return category IDs

`wp_get_post_categories` does not return category IDs or category names. It returns term objects. These objects contain names, descriptions, IDs, etc. I expect your code to be generating PHP warnings.

#### 5. Hardcoding Inline Styles

You shouldn't use inline styles. Use HTML classes

### The Correct Way To Do It

Use `post_class` to print out the posts html classes:

```php
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

This gives you classes you can target with CSS for post type, tags, categories, ID, etc etc. It does this automatically, so you doon't have to tell it to add the class.

Here's an example from my own site:

```html
<article id="post-931" class="post-931 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-development category-gutenberg tag-block-editor tag-comments tag-gutenberg tag-javascript tag-plugins tag-react tag-releases tag-wordpress">
```

`post_class` automatically generated those HTML classes for me, andif I added that post to a category named `test`, then `category-test` would appear on the frontend as a HTML class too.

So now you can target all posts in a category with a CSS file, resulting in nicer styling, smaller HTML, and easier to understand code, e.g.

```css
.category-development { 
    background: red;
}
```

Now all posts I write in the `development` category have a red background.

Don't forget the `body_class` function too. It adds HTML classes for the template used, archives, etc

---

A final note, don't end your PHP files in `?>`. It's not necessary and can actually cause an easily missed mistake with stray spaces aftering the closing tag breaking sites on older PHP versions.

Comment: Tom. I appreciate this option but I don't imagine create a post_class for each shop. I foresee about 5 categories for each of the 220 businesses. I'm creating all categories and attribute each of them inside each post , I can't imagine to recreate all specific post_class for each business. even if it's only half of them which have the same list of categories .

Comment: Why not? You're only setting the background colour of 4 categories, so that's only 4 CSS rules to create. You don't have to add or create any new categories or content that isn't already there. I think you've misunderstood. I don't understand why the number of business is relevant. Your test function checks if a post is inside one of 4 categoriies, this answer also does that, but it uses CSS not PHP to do it. Instead of using an inline style applied to posts that have 1 of 4 category IDs, it uses a CSS rule to posts that have 1 of 4 HTML classes

Comment: I will inquire about post_class. But for the moment with this page (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/) and your indications I do not see how to recover the categories of each article in post_class dynamically?
do you have an example?

Comment: How I associate a class from post_class to a category ? no example shows this

Comment: Tom, thanks so much for your time and answer. thanks to others too. sorry to be careless and novice. the problem come from the function. I call this inside foreach loop instead of outside.

Comment: function test($cats_post) must be called before if and foreach conditions

Comment: You don't have to do anything other than call `post_class`, it will add all the HTML classes for you automagically. E.g. if  add the category `test` to my post, then it will automatiically get `category-test` on the frontend. No extra work is needed, no code changes. It does everything for you